# Get REST API response (String Array) into Azure Stream Analytics

Tags: rest, azure, azure-stream-analytics

Hello Stack Overflow community members.

Can anyone recomend an approach to do the following within MS Azure standard service scope:
1. Call external REST API;
2. Get REST API response (that is string array) into Azure Stream Analytics (ASA) for further processing.

REST API (one to be called) can return both - JSON and XML (I guess JSON would be used in ASA case).

My intention is to do as little development as possible.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hi VSV. Unfortunately at this time it is not possible to call an external API within Azure Stream Analytics jobs. The only input you can use for your job are IoT Hub, Event Hub and Azure Blobs for streaming data; and Azure Blobs for reference data. Depending of your needs, you may consider using Azure Function to call the external API and integrate it with the rest of your architecture, including Azure Stream Analytics.

Comment: @JSAzure it seems that using Azure Functions to call external APIs is not permitted. Is there *any* other way - at all - to leverage an external API in Stream Analytics?

Comment: What error do you see? You can write your own code to call external APIs. See some example here: https://www.troyhunt.com/azure-functions-in-practice/

Comment: Azure Functions is an output, you cannot use its output in the query. Only other external API supported is Azure Machine Learning models. Can you describe your scenario a bit more? Is it possible to avoid the external call by either making it before sending data or by converting it into a lookup table?